# Can't resolve all parameters for AuthGuard

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, canactivate, angular-guards

I have this `AuthGuard`:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor (private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

And I have provided it in my `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [/*...*/],
  imports: [NotificationRoutingModule],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And i tried to use this guard in my routing module like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'notification',
    component: NotificationRootComponent
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'list', component: NotificationListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      {path: ':id', component: NotificationDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class NotificationRoutingModule {
}
```

And I get this error:

[image]

Did I miss something? Where is the source of this error?

**EDIT:** 
I am using Angular 4.4.6

It work fine when I use the basic route guard, and updated the route configurations:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'CannotBeActivated',
      useValue: () => {
        return false;
      }
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}


const routes = [
  {
    path: 'notification',
    component: NotificationRootComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'list', component: NotificationListComponent, canActivate: ['CannotBeActivated']},
      {path: ':id', component: NotificationDetailComponent, canActivate: ['CannotBeActivated']}
    ]
  }
];
```

**My tsconfig.json: **

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Okey, I have upadated my post.

Comment: Are you sure there  is @Injectable before export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just missed to put @Injectable() before your AuthGuard service

Comment: I have completely forgot this. Thank you!